# Select which enumerator use from variable value

Tags: vb.net, enums

I'm trying to make the generation of a table as dynamic as I can, but I'm facing a problem relative to the use of enums 
*(For example the header of the table has to display the all the possible enum value).*

In particular I'm dealing with the creation of a 2 dimensions UI table to make a breaf summary of the user's active projects where the table header (the columns) could be f.e. the project priority, and the rows could be f.e. the user who have created the project

```
       | high | normal | low  | 
-------+------+--------+------+
user_A |  5   |   8    |  3   |
-------+------+--------+------+
user_B |  7   |   0    |  1   |  
-------+------+--------+------+
```

In this scenario High, Normal, Low are part of the enum that defines the priority, but the same table structure could be applied if instead of the priority the user wants to see the different states the project has (Open, In Progress, Expired, Closed, etc.)
The user can also  swap columns and rows, but the table has to create the same result

The problem that I'm finding is that I don't know for sure if the header contains an enum or which enum is meant to be used by the user.
Is there a way to select which enum I've to use based on a variable value without making a `Select Case [variable_name]` with all the enums in my code?

I thought that maybe `System.Enum.Parse` could use useful, but it requires the `System.Type` information as its first argument, not a variable with the type name as value

For reference I'm trying to obtain the following situation

```
Public Enum foo
    a = 0
    b = 1
End Enum

Public Enum foo1
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = 2
End Enum

Dim var As String = "foo"
Dim choosenEnum As [var_value]
For Each val As Integer In choosenEnum.GetValues
    System.Enum.GetName([var_value], val)
    'add the found name to the table
Next
```

Comment: What is a *Table*?. *the header of the table has to display the all the possible enum value* : IMO, this requires a better definition. Is the *Header* actually the collection of Column names of *something*? Where/how is this meant to be used? *which enum is meant to be used by the user*: do Users use Enums? What are these enumerators?

Comment: I've added a quick example of what I'm trying to achieve. As you pointed out the header of the table has to display all the possible enum value, but I cannot create a dedicated header for every enum in my code because there are too many, even if I use a `Select Case` for each enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem, basically you can try to get the type from a string using the following function `Type.GetType(<string with full enum name>)`
Keep in mind that the string must be created in the following format: `[dll name].[class name]+[enum name]`